# how to change list column internal name

Tags: sharepoint, lookup, lookupfield, lookup-field

in sharepoint i have a list,

i have a lookup field from another list,

lets call my list as FirstList and the other list as SecondList.

```
 SecondList
   -ID
   -Title


 FirstList
    -ID
    -Title
    -SecondList
    -SecondList:ID
```

when i look to SecondList:ID field internal name i saw it is written as

```
 SecondList_x003A_ID
```

but i want it as

```
SecondList_x003a_ID
```

--> as a result i want to change the internal name of a field.

Answer (score 0):

`_003A_` is what Sharepoint converts the colon character to.  You're not going to be able to change the internal name to something different without deleting and recreating that field.

If you're doing a decent amount of custom code in Sharepoint that uses the internal name of objects, I'd recommend not using special characters or spaces in the names of lists or columns.

So for instance, use SecondList_ID instead of SecondList:ID.  Once you've created the column you can always change the DisplayName of the column to whatever you want.  Same goes for lists and document libraries.

Comment: SecondList:ID field is a lookup column so it creates its name itself. in the project before this column was exists in list and its name was SecondList_x003A_ID. i deleted it and readded it. now its name becomes SecondList_x003a_ID. but i want it to be created as SecondList_x003A_ID.

Comment: In your original post you said that you wanted the internal name to be "SecondList_x003a_ID" not "SecondList_x003A_ID".  Are you now saying the opposite?  That you want the internal name with a lowercase "a"?  If that is the case, you might have to created the column with the name "SecondList_x003a_ID", then change the DisplayName to "SecondList:ID" so you can get the DisplayName you want and the InternalName you want.

Comment: SecondList:ID field is a lookup column so it creates its name itself. What should i do?